# In GDI+, I'm drawing a arc and a circle with the save center point and radius, but the graphics are separated

Tags: c#, gdi+

I'm new to GDI+, and I'm writing a program to draw a circle and arc segments on the circle using GDI+'s `DrawArc` and `DrawElllipse`, but in some cases, the arc is not on the circle in the outcome graphic.Here is one of the test data that reproduce the problem：

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AutiAlias;
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
//data
float x = -104852.81f;
float y = -159215f;
float r = 190885.281f;
float start_angle = 0.987f;
float sweep_angle = 0.0002f;
//draw
g.DrawEllipse(pen, x-r, y-r, 2*r, 2*r);
g.DrawArc(pen, x-r, y-r, 2*r, 2*r, start_angle*180.0f/(float)Math.PI, sweep_angle*180.0f/(float)Math.PI);
```

[here is the graphic i've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekdu1.jpg)

Is this a problem of GDI+ or my wrong use of the API?

Comment: See [How arcs are drawn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawarc?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Comment: See also [How ellipses are drawn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawellipse?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)